# How to access Kubernetes cluster nodes in WSL

Tags: kubernetes, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-desktop

I have setup a kubernetes cluster using WSL (Ubuntu 20.x) and Docker Desktop using below blog

https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/05/21/wsl-docker-kubernetes-on-the-windows-desktop/

I created a 3 node cluster using kinD utility

```
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
  - role: control-plane
  - role: worker
  - role: worker
```

I also created an nginx deployment and a service on it with a Node port. How can I access the port from Windows browser ? I am unable to access it using **http://127.0.0.1:nodeport**

```
$kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME                       STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE       KERNEL-VERSION                CONTAINER-RUNTIME
my-cluster-control-plane   Ready    master   46m   v1.17.0   172.17.0.4    <none>        Ubuntu 19.10   4.19.128-microsoft-standard   containerd://1.3.2
my-cluster-worker          Ready    <none>   45m   v1.17.0   172.17.0.2    <none>        Ubuntu 19.10   4.19.128-microsoft-standard   containerd://1.3.2
my-cluster-worker2         Ready    <none>   45m   v1.17.0   172.17.0.3    <none>        Ubuntu 19.10   4.19.128-microsoft-standard   containerd://1.3.2
```

I am unable to reach the node IPs 172.17.0.x from my windows browser, how can I access the node ports exposed by the nginx service ?

PS: **kubectl port-forward** works when I expose the port on the Pod directly. I can access the nginx server directly using **http://127.0.0.1:forwardport** from windows browser. But, I want to use services and nodeport without need for port forwarding

Comment: You [have to expose those ports](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start/#mapping-ports-to-the-host-machine); that 172 address is a figment of docker's imagination and does not (AFAIK) correspond to any network interface on your machine

Answer (score 0):

I know it might be late, but I just wanted to share as I have been struggling with this myself installing microk8s directly on WSL, no Docker, no KinD. To solve this I wrote a small utility script available as helm chart on github that exposes ports in a way understandable by WSL => available on localhost.

Of course deployed service has to be of type Load Balancer or Node Port to be exposed. Otherwise it is only internal to the cluster if not exposed via Ingress or kubectl port-forward.

You can read more about this here:

- https://devopsifyme.com/how-to-access-k8ss-node-ports-using-wsl/
- https://devopsifyme.com/how-to-run-microk8s-on-your-wsl-with-ubuntu-22-04/